# Xamarin app has to be manually uninstalled to be deployed

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

So i'm developing with `Xamarin` on `Visual Studio 2017` and whenever I want to 'deploy' or debug the app on my phone (`OnePlus A3000` if that matters) I need to uninstall the previous version from my phone and only then deploy again the app.

The problem flow as follows:

- Depoly app first time. (all good)
- Running and debugging the app. (all good)
- Deploy again (another version). -> can't be done if I don't uninstall the app.

**Goal:** Deploy the app without manually uninstalling every time.

Output:

```
3> Deployment failed
3>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install com.zebra.teller without first uninstalling.]
3>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
3>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
3>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
3>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
3>Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install com.zebra.teller without first uninstalling.]
3>Touching "obj\Debug\upload.flag".
3>Done building project "Zebra.Teller.csproj".
3>Build succeeded.
3>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
3>Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install com.zebra.teller without first uninstalling.]
```

Comment: I've seen a OnePlus bug about the adb `INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS` issue as I was researching a related problem for a client, search Xamarin's bugzilla (and the Xamarin.Android issues at their GitHub repo).

Comment: @SushiHangover I have already done that and I can't find any solution whatsoever.

Comment: I know that there was at least one issue reported concerning OnePlus, I would try to repeat a debug deploy via **Android Studio** to confirm if it is a Visual Studio issue with how they are using `adb`, or if it is a OS/firmware phone related issue.

Comment: @SushiHangover I have found the issue referring to oneplus 3 but It didn't help. and that's an issue with visual studio and adb from my experience.

Comment: Try and do a manual reinstall (-r`) via adb and see if you get the same error.